# Grouping HTML elements and create a new eleme

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Please consider I am having below codes which is a set of elements for selecting and showing date.

```
<div>
   <input type="text" class="txt txtDate"/>
   <input type="button" class="btn btnDate" value="Select from Calendar"/>
   <span class="remainedDays"></span>
<div>
```

Here I have an input for entering date, a button for selecting date from a calendar, and a label which shows difference between selected date and current date. All calculations and form interactions is handling by JavaScript and jQuery.

Since I use this date picker in many forms I'm looking for a way to define this elements in a new element and use new element. If I can do this I will write less codes and any change in in definition of new element will be automatically applied in all forms.

I am looking for something like this:

`<mydatepicker class="dt1"></mydatepicker>` or `<mydatepicker class="dt1"/>`

which should be rendered in browser as

```html
    <div class="dt1">
       <input type="text" class="txt txtDate"/>
       <input type="button" class="btn btnDate" value="Select from Calendar"/>
       <span class="remainedDays"></span>
    <div>
```

Comment: look for react component

Comment: Look at this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like `angular.js directive` or `Angular Component` with pure JavaScript code.

You can create `Web Component` by extending `HTMLElement` and also you can get all attributes and class list of that custom `Element` to create more powerful and dynamic component:

```js
class mydatepicker  extends HTMLElement {
            Classes;
            CustomLabel;
            constructor() {
                super();
                this.classes = this.classList.value;
                this.CustomLabel = this.getAttribute("CustomLabel");
            }


            connectedCallback() {
                this.innerHTML = `
                <div class="${this.classes}">
                      <label> ${this.CustomLabel} </label>
                       <input type="text" class="txt txtDate"/>
                       <input type="button" class="btn btnDate" value="Select from Calendar"/>
                       <span class="remainedDays"></span>
                <div>
              `;
            }

        }

        customElements.define("my-datepicker", mydatepicker);
```

```css
.dt1{
   color:red;
}
```

```html
<my-datepicker  class="dt1 dt2" CustomLabel="this is custome lable"> </my-datepicker>
```

Note that you can pass some classes and custom attribute you want

Comment: Am I supposed add some files or references to my project?

Comment: @Behnam No this code is based on pure JavaScript. I just mentioned that your requirement is something like `angular.js directive` . But my snippet works without any external reference. just run and see the result

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom element in Vanilla JavaScript, but really not worth the hassle, I suggest you start using JavaScript frameworks for this kind of thing.

But anyway, you can do it in vanilla javascript like this:

First create a JavaScript file (e.g, `c-element.js`) and extend the `HTMLElement` class. Inside it's `connectedCallback` method, write the HTML content you'd like to render.

Then add the script to your HTML file, and just use the custom element's tag!

Of course, this is just a really simple example, you can add to it however you want. You can read the documentation on creating custom elements [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements).

```js
class CElement extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        this.innerHTML = `
      <div class="c-element">
      <div class="c-element__heading">
      <h1> This is a custom element (CElement)</h1>
        </div>
        </div>
      `;
    }
}

customElements.define("c-element", CElement);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<c-element> </c-element>
<script src="c-element.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```